# Check a checkbox based on a query value returned from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i have a checkbox in a form that is unchecked and i run a query in php to update the form i need the checkbox to be checked when MYSQL value is 1 and unchecked for any other value (usually 0 but could be NULL)
i have run the query and can place the value into a text field and this was to make sure i was returning something and yes it is either 1 or 0.
hoping all i need is a simple if statement but have yet been unable to create one that works.

i have run a query that is called $query6 and this returns all the values needed for the form and i am calling values like so $rows['MaxxeBasic'] being the column name in the mysql table.

the code below is an input that is checked but should change based on the return from the $query6 for the $rows['MaxxeBasic']

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_9_0" name="q9_sitePackage[]" value="' . $rows['MaxxeBasic'] . '" checked="checked"   />
```

The following line of code show a list of some the additional checkboxes i will need to deal with however once i have managed the first one the others should be straight forward.

```
    echo '<li class="form-line" id="id_9">
    <label class="form-label-left" id="label_9" for="input_9"> Site Package </label>
    <div id="cid_9" class="form-input">
      <div class="form-single-column"><span class="form-checkbox-item" style="clear:left;">



          <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_9_0" name="q9_sitePackage[]" value="' . $rows['MaxxeBasic'] . '" checked="checked"   />
          <input class="form-textbox form-address-city" type="text" name="q5_address5[city]" id="input_5_city" size="21" value="' . $rows['MaxxeBasic'] . '"/>
          <label for="input_9_0"> Maxxe-Basic </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span><span class="form-checkbox-item" style="clear:left;">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_9_1" name="q9_sitePackage[]" value="' . $rows['MaxxeStd'] . '" />
          <label for="input_9_1"> Maxxe-Basic Plus </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span><span class="form-checkbox-item" style="clear:left;">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_9_2" name="q9_sitePackage[]" value="' . $rows['MaxxeMore'] . '" />
          <label for="input_9_2"> Maxxe-Std </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span><span class="form-checkbox-item" style="clear:left;">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_9_3" name="q9_sitePackage[]" value="' . $rows['MaxxeBasicPlus'] . '" />
          <label for="input_9_3"> Maxxe-Std Plus </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span><span class="form-checkbox-item" style="clear:left;">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_9_4" name="q9_sitePackage[]" value="' . $rows['MaxxeStdPlus'] . '" />
          <label for="input_9_4"> Maxxe-More </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span><span class="form-checkbox-item" style="clear:left;">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_9_5" name="q9_sitePackage[]" value="' . $rows['MaxxeMorePlus'] . '" />
          <label for="input_9_5"> Maxxe-More Plus </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>';
```

Comment: Get results from db and then do it in while loop. This code I am using modify it with your code.
**while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) !=false) {
                   
                   $selected = ($row['makeid'] == $make) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                   echo "<option value=".$row['makeid']." $selected>".$row['make']."</option>";
                  }**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_9_0" name="q9_sitePackage[]" value="' . $rows['MaxxeBasic'] . '"'. ($rows['MaxxeBasic'] == 1 ? ' checked="checked"' : '').'   />
```